# T-SQL IF ELSE logic using COUNTS in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The problem I am trying to solve for is using `IF/ELSE` logic within a `SELECT` statement and evaluating the calculated `COUNT`.

If the calculated count is zero, leave as is. Else - subtract 1.

I need some help revising my code below to include this kind of logic:

```
COUNT (case when d2.dwContactPK = 0 then d2.dwContactPK end) + COUNT(distinct   d2.dwContactPK)-1 as [AG1],

COUNT(case when d.GeneratedToTMYN = 'Y' and d2.dwContactPK = 0 then d2.dwContactPK end) + 
    COUNT(distinct case when d.GeneratedToTMYN = 'Y' then d2.dwContactPK end) -1 as [AG2],


COUNT(case when d.GeneratedToEloquaSFDCYN = 'Y' and d2.dwContactPK = 0 then d2.dwContactPK end) + 
    COUNT(distinct case when d.GeneratedToEloquaSFDCYN = 'Y' then d2.dwContactPK end) -1 as [AG3],
```

Comment: are you trying to count the records?

Answer (score 0):

```
select case
        when d2.dwContactPK = 0 then d2.dwContactPK
        else COUNT(distinct   d2.dwContactPK)-1
        end as MyAnswer
```

Comment: I hope this helps you with the syntax that you will need to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your question appears to be:

> The problem I am trying to solve for is using IF/ELSE logic within a
>   SELECT statement and evaluating the calculated COUNT.

I am unclear how the code samples you have relate to this question.  The structure of the answer is:

```
select (case when count( . . . ) = 0 then 0
             else count( . . . ) - 1
        end)
```

The `. . .` might include `case` statements, but not other aggregation functions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of your input. I ended up enclosing each of the statements in a larger 'case when' clause which did the trick. It's probably not the prettiest approach, but it gets the job done here:

```
Case when(COUNT(case when d2.dwContactPK = 0 then d2.dwContactPK end) + 
COUNT(distinct d2.dwContactPK) -1) = -1 then 0 else COUNT(case when d2.dwContactPK = 0 then d2.dwContactPK end) + 
COUNT(distinct d2.dwContactPK) -1 end as [AG1],


Case when(COUNT(case when d.GeneratedToTMYN = 'Y' and d2.dwContactPK = 0 then d2.dwContactPK end) + 
COUNT(distinct case when d.GeneratedToTMYN = 'Y' then d2.dwContactPK end) -1) = -1 then 0 else COUNT(case when d.GeneratedToTMYN = 'Y' and d2.dwContactPK = 0 then d2.dwContactPK end) + 
COUNT(distinct case when d.GeneratedToTMYN = 'Y' then d2.dwContactPK end) -1 end as [AG2],


Case when(COUNT(case when d.GeneratedToEloquaSFDCYN = 'Y' and d2.dwContactPK = 0 then d2.dwContactPK end) + 
COUNT(distinct case when d.GeneratedToEloquaSFDCYN = 'Y' then d2.dwContactPK end) -1) = -1 then 0 else COUNT(case when d.GeneratedToEloquaSFDCYN = 'Y' and d2.dwContactPK = 0 then d2.dwContactPK end) + 
COUNT(distinct case when d.GeneratedToEloquaSFDCYN = 'Y' then d2.dwContactPK end) -1 end as [AG3],
```